# Is there a way of displaying my dynamic public IP with html?

Tags: html

I currently run a Minecraft server for a friend but due to my IP being dynamic, I'm forever telling him the updating public IP.

I was wondering if there was a html code which I could put on my website to display the updating IP.

(And yes I could lease the IP to stay the same, but that would mean buying a more updated Router. I'm trying to keep the cost down)

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. It's a markup language.

Comment: Any other languages which can display it in web format?

Comment: You would need some sort of server side script that generated the html page with your ip address in it. HTML itself cant do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use dynamic dns (DDNS) service. Even the cheapest routers are providing that service. It shouldn't be hard to find free service and after setting it up, your friend can just ping yours subdomain (for IP) or use hostname.

Example, for tp-link: http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-297.html

It is not possible to achieve that with HTML as it runs on client computer (yours friend computer).

Comment: I hadn't though of that, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try via server side with JSONP

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

There is many different way to handle this.
The first (and better) one is to use an Dynamic DNS. Google can find you many good DDNS providers. Or you can find some here : https://serverfault.com/questions/68021/reliable-cheap-or-free-dns-service.

If you don't want to use an DDNS service and if you're on linux, you can make a small shell script that will send a file with you're IP address to your website. You'll just need to add this script to a crontask.

Ex :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl v4.ident.me -o /tmp/my_ip.txt
scp /tmp/my_ip.txt me@myServer.com:/my/website/path/
```

Even if this solution can work, i REALLY do not recommend it.